# content frame navigation not working - silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new in silverlight and facing one navigation issue from one page to another page.
Here is my scenario

I have one page named, page1.xaml. In this page i have placed one navigation frame and loading login.xaml page in it.

Now, on the button click (on successful login),i need to to move to page2.xaml (which is another master page kind) and it also contains another frame, And i  need to initially load, myaccount.xaml page in this page.

Now, what i have done so far is.
In app.xaml page,

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
{
Panel grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(new MasterSimple());
this.RootVisual = grid;       
}
```

The above code because, i want to change the root visual from page1.xaml to page2.xaml

Now in the page1.xaml, here is my frame

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"  Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle2}" 
                    Template="{StaticResource CustomTransitioningNavFrame}" Margin="0,8,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="270" Width="640">
<navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
<uriMapper:UriMapper>
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/{pageName}.xaml"/>
</uriMapper:UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

and on page1.xaml constructor,

```
this.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Loginnew", UriKind.Relative));
```

So the above code, shows me my page1.xaml page with Loginnew.xaml in frame. This is good.
Now in the loginnew.xaml page, i have one button and its click i need to navigate to page2.xaml page. i wrote the below code on button click

```
MasterTest2 currentPresentationPage = new MasterTest2();

(App.Current.RootVisual as Panel).Children.Clear();
(App.Current.RootVisual as Panel).Children.Add(currentPresentationPage);
```

And on page2.xaml page, i have this frame

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"  Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}"  
                           Navigating="ContentFrame_Navigating" Template="{StaticResource FrameControlTemplate1}">
</navigation:Frame>
```

and on its constructor,

```
 ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/myaccount", UriKind.Relative));
```

This is my structure of the program.

Now my problem is when i click on the login page button, it shows me page2.xaml page. but in page2.xaml page it loads Loginnew.xaml page only, it does not load the myaccount.xaml page.
I have also mark that when i navigate to page2.xaml, the URL in address bar is changed to 
http://www.abc.com/test.aspx#Loginnew

Is it the reason why myaccount.xaml page is not loading? What should i have to do to load myaccount.xaml page in the page2.xaml's frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Loginnew", UriKind.Relative));
```

I have move the above code from constructor to Frame's loaded event and it start to work. :)

Comment: you should not add this as a commt, rather edit your original question!

Comment: @Marek Actualy, i saw a button of "Answer Your question", so i click it. Dont you think its right? If not then i will take care next time.

Comment: @user867198 You absolutely should post answers to your own questions as soon as you find them. That's why you got +1 from me. I only edited the answer to add code formatting.